# How to grab youtube video title if we have link to the video

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am using [this](https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox) code in my website. Can I grab youtube title with following code,

```
function setYouTubeTitle(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.protocol + '//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
            data: {
                q: "select * from json where url ='http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id + "&format=json'",
                format: "json"
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.json) {
                    YouTubeDialog.dialog({
                       title: data.query.results.json.title
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Author of the code suggest to put this code in `onNavigate` event. I use link in my site like below. I don't know how to do it.

```
<a href="https://youtu.be/youtube_id" data-toggle="lightbox"><\a>
```

Comment: Since [YQL is not longer available](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), you should use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) for retrieve the information you want.

Comment: Not a coder. Please explain how to do it in my code

Comment: you have to get involved a little in coding for complete your task. I'll post an answer and so you'll be able to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to getting familiar with coding for complete this task. I hope that with this answer you can take a look and check that it is not too difficult.

---

First, you have to use YouTube Data API v3.

[Read the documentation of YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) for get **`API_KEY`** *(which will allow you to use the API)*.

Once you have your **`API_KEY`**, you can use the following API request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=D3Me6YNe9tg&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Ftitle&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Where `{YOUR_API_KEY}` is the value of the **`API_KEY`** and **`id`** is the **`videoId`** you want get the **`title`**.

In the previous URL, we set the value of the **videoId** property to `hjGZLnja1o8`.

If you test this API request [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=hjGZLnja1o8&fields=items%252Fsnippet%252Ftitle&_h=2&), you'll get the following results:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Nightcore - Rockefeller Street"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

---

If you insists in use another way for complete this task, you can also browse here in Stack Overflow or in Google and search: `get title of url javascript`, but, I wouldn't spend much time on it since YouTube has some restrictions for requests *(without using its API)*. So, long story short: **use the YouTube Data API v3**.